# How do I install eclipse PDE?

Tags: eclipse, installation

I have already installed the eclipse IDE for Java developers (Helios Service Release 2)

How do I now install the Plug-in Developers Environment (PDE) on top of that? I thought that it should be possible to install it from an update site, like any other eclipse plug-in. But I can't find the correct update site anywhere.

Comment: It is possible, you just to use the aggregated Helios update site. The name of the feature is "_Eclipse Plug-in Development Environment_"

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Try that in Eclipse:

Help → Install New Software... → Choose *The Eclipse Project Updates* in field *Work With* → Filter for *RCP Plug-In*

Then press <kbd>Next</kbd> and follow the instructions!

Comment: NB: filtering for "RCP Plug-In" seems to work for eclipse 3.6 only, before that it was called something else.

Comment: Now the filter should be `Eclipse plug-in` and then tick `Eclipse plug-in Development Environment` in Luna release.

Comment: With Eclipse Mars, I had to use "Plugin: in search and select Eclipse Plugin development (PDE) to install it.

Comment: For Oxygen release,
->Help ->Install new software ->Work with -> dropdown -> Eclipse Project updates ->Eclipse Plugin Development Resources/Environment

Answer (score 7):

For Eclipse IDE for Java Developers Juno SR2, go to:
Help -> Install New Software -> In field "Work with" select "Juno - http://download.eclipse.org/releases/juno", then Expand  General Purpose Tools, then select Eclipse Plug-in Development Environment, then just go to Next, Next, Accept policy, Finish, Restart Eclipse when prompted to do so. Welcome page should be now opened and there you can see big icon (beside others) for Eclipse plug-in development. If not, go to Windows, Show View, Other and there look for "Plug-in Development". Expand and choose what you need.

Comment: Works for Luna as well. Tried on "Luna Service Release 1a".

Comment: `Eclipse plug-in development environment` comes with `ant` 1.9.2. For a more recent version ant has to be installed manually.

Answer (score 5):

This is in eclipse repository :

http://blog.ankursharma.org/2009/08/how-do-i-install-pde_20.html