# How do I install eclipse PDE on Indigo (3.7)

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, installation, eclipse-pde

I just re-installed eclipse, using the latest version (Indigo / 3.7), and I run into the exact same problem as I did half a year ago. I installed the eclipse java IDE, now how do I get the plugin development enviroment (PDE) working?

I've installed the RCP components as in my previous question: 
[How do I install eclipse PDE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6177034/how-do-i-install-eclipse-pde)

Although installation of the RCP components completes as expected, it's somehow not enabled. I can't create OSGi run configurations, there is no Target Platform entry in the preferences dialog, and there is no option to convert a project to a plug-in.

Do I need to install something else? Is there anything I have to do to manually enable the PDE?

Comment: One thing to remember is to search for "plug-in", not "plugin".  No idea why they have that hyphen in the middle of the word.  Also, if you don't see it on the list, it might already be installed (it's sometimes installed by default in Eclipse bundles).  Uncheck the "Hide items that are already installed" to see.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you downloaded the Eclipse IDE for Java Developers then you will not have PDE pre-installed. It is included in the Eclipse Classic download. The simplest way to obtain PDE is:

1. In the menu goto Help --> Install New Software.
2. In the Available Software dialog select the Indigo site (http://download.eclipse.org/releases/indigo) from the "Work with" drop down.
3. In the search box enter the phrase "Plug-in" this should filter the list so you can see the Eclipse Plug-in Development Environment.
4. Click the checkbox and finish and install.

In step 3 you can also get to it by expanding "General Purpose Tools" and then scrolling down to Eclipse Plug-in Development Environment.

Comment: You're right. In hindsight, my mistake was to install "Eclipse RCP Plug-in developers resources" from "http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/3.7" instead of "Eclipse Plug-in Development Environment" from "http://download.eclipse.org/releases/indigo"

Answer (score 1):

Go to Window --> Open Perspective --> Plug-in Development.

This should show some of the features that you are missing.

Comment: Nope. Plug-in Development perspective is not in the list. I'm thinking the RPC components are somehow not enabled properly, but I have no idea how to fix that.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone coming to this page in the future, The package you want to install is the:

```
Eclipse SDK
```

Which I found on the the http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/3.7 update site