# Eclipse OSGi run configuration

Tags: eclipse, osgi

Is there any way to add OSGi Run configuration to Eclipse Indigo if there's no such section in a templates panel on the left of  "Run Configurations" dialog box?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Download the [Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers](http://eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-ee-developers/indigosr1) package. It looks to me that [PDE](http://www.eclipse.org/pde/pde-ui/) is required for the OSGi Framework launch configuration which is [missing](http://eclipse.org/downloads/compare.php) from the *Eclipse IDE for Java Developers* package.

> PDE UI also provides comprehensive OSGi tooling, which makes it an
>   ideal environment for component programming, not just Eclipse plug-in
>   development.
>
> ...
>
> Launchers - test and debug Eclipse applications and
>   OSGi bundles.

(From http://www.eclipse.org/pde/pde-ui/)

Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7391778/how-do-i-install-eclipse-pde-on-indigo-3-7/7393994#7393994) too. Installing the PDE plugin through *Install New Software* also could be a solution.