# Eclipse does a clean build instead of incremental

Tags: eclipse, build

I have an issue here that is driving me crazy. :D

I have been working with eclipse (Juno version) for about a year now.
All of a sudden, without me realizing if I did change anything, every time eclipse does a build, it treats it as a clean-build: it removes everything from my output folder, compiles all of my class files and then copies resources.

This is taking A LOONG time.
Before this weird behavior, build always took much much less time (3 seconds compared to 4 minutes that it's is taking now).

- I have tried downloading a new version of eclipse.
- I have tried copying my project in a new workspace.
- Automatic build is NOT selected.
- It is NOT the case that build does the clean-build every time. But it looks like it tries to do a clean build ever 5 minute or so when I attempt a build.

Reading eclipse documentation, it should do an incremental build, detecting only the changes I have made rather than a clean build.
Do you guys have any clue as to why this is happening?

I GREATLY appreciate ANY help!

Thank you!!!

Comment: It seems that own org.eclipse.core.resources.builders extension is [the only way to achieve your goal](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Fguide%2FresAdv_builders.htm). [Here's relevant wiki page](http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_implement_an_incremental_project_builder%3F) and [step-by-step tutorial](https://sites.google.com/site/eclipseplugindevelopment/builders-natures-and-markers)(though it requires installed [PDE](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7393994/2286990)).

Comment: Maybe you should turn on automatic builds?  When you go to the project's "Builders" Properties page, is the Java Builder still there and not replaced by something else?  Is the project on a local disk? Could something else be marking those files as changed and needing to be built?

Comment: Thank you guys for the comments. I did check that the "Java Builder" was the only builder for me. In the end I wasn't able to find out what was wrong, but "downloading a new eclipse" and "using a new workspace/ new project setup" worked. I will update this thread if I find more info! Thank you for taking the time to answer. :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding Builders to Project in Eclipse and Incremental-ness](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7434400/adding-builders-to-project-in-eclipse-and-incremental-ness)

Answer (score 0):

I was encountering the same issue with one project in Eclipse (C project/CDT), but not another similar version of the project and couldn't figure out why for the longest time.  I finally stumbled upon this forum entry: [Eclipse Forum](https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php?t=msg&th=1041822&goto=1719753&#msg_1719753)

The solution for me was in this response:

> In Project Properties > C/C++ Build, there is a "Refresh Policy" tab on the preference page. I've found that the issue I've reported stops when I add the root of the project to the resources to be refreshed (therefore, I have only the root folder in the list of resources to refresh).
>
> I was baffled when I discovered that, and just to be certain, I repeatedly added and removed the root folder. Each time, the problem stopped then came back.

Sure enough looking at the same property in the project that worked and it was set correctly.  Not sure how it became unset in the project that was failing, but setting it to the base project directory fixes the build process for this project.