# PDE UI & PHP Development How to install

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, ide, eclipse-pde, eclipse-luna

i need to finde PDE UI and, i was looking llike for 2 days,

I migrated java ide and java ee ide of eclipse.

I have Eclipse Java EE IDE 4.4(Luna).

I need all of them on same instalation.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I install eclipse PDE?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6177034/how-do-i-install-eclipse-pde)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Eclipse open `Help > Install New Software`

Select `Luna - http://download.eclipse.org/releases/luna` in the `Work with` section.

Open the `General Purpose Tools` section and check `Eclipse Plug-in Development Environment`.

Click Next to start the install.